# Prometheus client integration

Tags: prometheus

I'd like to integrate Prometheus into my system and am wondering about the amount of work that needs doing. I already have the ability to present JSON formatted data to HTTP endpoints (so external systems can currently GET a limited amount of information already) - is it just a case of adding a new 'prometheus formatted' endpoint so the prometheus server can scrape from it? I'm not worried about pushing

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the metrics, then exposing it over HTTP in the Prometheus text format will do the trick.

If possible you should use one of the existing client libraries to do so for you, as it'll handle the little details like escaping.